# objective-c: NSMutableString must start with a \n character

Tags: objective-c, debugging, logging

Okay, this is weird as hell, and I just want a sanity check to prove that I am not hallucinating from the lack of sleep.

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++){
        [s appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ", arr[i][j]]];
    }
    [s appendString:@"\n"];
}
NSLog(s);
```

The Log window displays all contents in arr except the first row. 
If I change the first line to

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"\n"];
```

it prints correctly.

Any reasonable explanations?

Comment: Is it possible that the first element of the array is being printed, but it's coming right after the timestamp in the log and you're not noticing it? :)

Comment: Sorry, no-repro. Check the sizes in your array declaration. Also, `NSLog` wants a string literal and a format string (it should be giving you a warning) -- this is unlikely to cause an actual error, but you should change it to: `NSLog(@"%@", s);`

Comment: @Jonathan, good catch, that's exactly what happend, it hanging on to the end of the previous line. Thanks all. I can sleep without nightmares now.

Comment: @Jonathan @Haoest:  One of you needs to write that up as the answer and then Haoest needs to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: Is it possible that the first element of the array is being printed, but it's coming right after the timestamp in the log and you're not noticing it?